# NextJs: "TypeError: replace is not a function" when start test with Jest

Tags: reactjs, next.js, jestjs

It is a NavBar component with a Search input that redirects to another page where it shows the result. This is using a **"replace"** instead of a **"push".**

```
        import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
        import { IconButton, TextField } from "@mui/material";
        import { Search } from "@mui/icons-material";
        import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

        export const SearchHeader = (queryType: any) => {
          const { replace } = useRouter();
          const [searchTerm, setSearchTerm] = useState("");
          const [rutaPath, setRutaPath] = useState("");

          useEffect(() => {
            setRutaPath(`../../search/${queryType}/`);
          }, [queryType]);

          const onSearchTerm = () => {
            if (searchTerm.trim().length === 0) return;
            return replace(`${rutaPath}${searchTerm}`);
          };

          return (
            <>
              <TextField
                sx={{ input: { color: "white" }, border: { color: "white" } }}
                hiddenLabel
                id="filled-hidden-label-small"
                variant="filled"
                size="small"
                className="ms-3"
                color="warning"
                focused
                inputProps={{ "data-testid": "searchinput" }}
                aria-label="searchinput"
                placeholder="Search..."
                autoFocus
                value={searchTerm}
                onChange={(e) => setSearchTerm(e.target.value)}
                onKeyPress={(e) => (e.key === "Enter" ? onSearchTerm() : null)}
                type="text"
              />
              <IconButton
                onClick={(e) => onSearchTerm()}
                aria-label="search"
                sx={{ color: "white" }}
                size="large"
              >
                <Search />
              </IconButton>
            </>
          );
        };
```

Test file should check if Search fail and return error message:

```
            import { NavBar } from "@/components/ui";
            import {
              render,
              screen,
              fireEvent,
              waitFor,
            } from "@testing-library/react";

            jest.mock("next/navigation", () => ({
              useRouter() {
                return {
                  replace: "../../search/medics/",
                };
              },
            }));

            beforeEach(() => render(<NavBar />));

            describe("NavBar Search Input", () => {
            
              it('must show a empty state message "no encontramos ningun caso con el termino"', async () => {
                fireEvent.change(screen.getByTestId("searchinput"), {
                  target: { name: "name", value: "electronic" },
                });
                fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /search/i }));
                await waitFor(() =>
                  fireEvent.click(screen.getByRole("button", { name: /search/i }))
                );
                await waitFor(() =>
                  expect(
                    screen.getByText(/no encontramos ningun caso con el termino/i)
                  ).toBeInTheDocument()
                );
              });
            });
```

But test returns this message "replace is not a function":

```
   ● NavBar › must show a empty state message "You search has no results"

   TypeError: replace is not a function

     20 |     if (searchTerm.trim().length === 0) return;
     21 |
   > 22 |     return replace(`${rutaPath}${searchTerm}`);
        |            ^
     23 |   };
```

I can't find any documentation about this case. Has anyone been this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`useRouter` is exported by `next/router`, so I think you need to update your import statement on your main file and also in the test file.

Comment: Thanks for your aswer. It seems this is changed since a few weeks ago. https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/routing/linking-and-navigating